# optimize rest API for HTTP/2 or HTTP/3

Tags: rest, http, https

I found out from *multiple sources* <sup>[1](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1r7QXGYOLCh4fcUq0jDdDwKJWNqWK1o4xMtYpKZCJYjM/edit#slide=id.p19) [2](https://livebook.manning.com/book/http2-in-action/chapter-6/) [3](https://blog.cloudflare.com/http-2-for-web-developers/) [4](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/getting-ready-for-http2/) [5](https://unused-css.com/blog/what-http2-means-for-frontend-development/) [6](https://medium.com/swlh/http-2-and-website-optimization-b919cd0de7b5) [7](https://yoast.com/performance-optimization-http2/) [8](https://hpbn.co/optimizing-application-delivery/#optimizing-for-http2) [9](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ways-improve-websites-pagespeed-using-http2/)</sup> that we do not need to do the following to optimize our rest API for HTTP/2 or HTTP/3:

1. domain sharding
2. concatenating assets
3. inlining assets
4. turning multiple image files into sprites
5. not inline images in CSS using data URIs

However, I am not sure if this is the complete picture. is there anything more to optimize our rest API for HTTP/2 or HTTP/3? Is there any more benefits we can have as a web developer when using HTTP/2 or HTTP/3?

Just to be clear, i am not talking about backward compatibility or anything. I just want to know - if I am sure my API will be served using HTTP/2 or HTTP/3 and my API will only be accessed by clients who support HTTP/2 or HTTP/3 then what optimizations / benefits (things I do not have to do anymore) can I have.

One more thing. Chromium developers have [announced](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/K3rYLvmQUBY/m/vOWBKZGoAQAJ?pli=1) that they plan to remove support for HTTP/2 server push from the browser engine. So please suggest optimization that do not include server push.

Comment: This will likely be closed as 'too broad', but your API can still massively benefit from HTTP/2 if your client does a good job fetching things in parallel. I wrote a bit about it here: https://evertpot.com/h2-parallelism/ . Push plays a role here, but we also still use compound responses despite being on HTTP/2 for some stuff. Hit me up privately if you want to know more!

Comment: I don't really want to write an essay about such a general question, and it's not really the purpose of stack overflow anyway. I'm just offering a conversation.

Comment: @Evert do you have any resources on cpu usage vs bandwidth usage trade off when updating from HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2 or HTTP/3